# OpenID, Gmail, Facebook, Yahoo login for Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, authentication, openid

Is there somethink like [this](http://codecanyon.k42b3.com/openid/openid.php#) for free for wordpress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word press has an openid [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/). I am not sure if it works with the other login services.

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/) can do also other services like

> Quickly register and login users with their existing accounts from Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo!, LinkedIn, Windows Live, MySpace, AOL or OpenID

Comment: That plugin is supposedly broken... See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/is-there-a-a-better-openid-plugin-for-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/19/wordpress-third-party-accounts-login-plugin/) goes into some detail on how to use the [OpenID](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/) plugin for Wordpress.  It doesn't look like Facebook is supported (although it is an OpenID provider) in terms of displaying icons, but Google, Yahoo, Flickr, and others are.