# Is there a a better OpenID plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, openid

The last version that came out for [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/) is 3.3.2, and it's broken. Whenever I click "Upgrade all my plugins", my openid gets broken and I can't login to Stack Overflow until I downgrade this plugin :)

Is there an alternative ?

Edit - I am looking mainly for OpenID **Provider** support. The Consumer support is nice to have.

Comment: Please ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: See this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/458/openid-for-wordpress-3-x

Answer (score 1):

I use [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/), and have never had a problem with it. Has a good [WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/) as well.

Comment: Does it work as an open-id provider as well?